# How to resolve Role based authentication using Keycloak in Spring webflux application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, api-gateway

I have created spring Webflux project for securing services I have used Keycloak. In Keycloak I have created two roles "admin" & "user" and two users user mapping to "user" role and admin mapping to "admin" role. in securityConfig class I have set one request for admin  and one request for user using hasRole("role") in config class.

controller.java

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/samp")
public class controller {

    @GetMapping
    public String display() {
        return " role is user";
    }
    @GetMapping("/a")
    public String displayA() {
        return " role is admin";
    }   @GetMapping("/b")
    public String displayaB() {
        return " role is gene";
    }
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    
     @Bean
     public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/samp/a").hasRole("admin")
                .pathMatchers("/samp/b").hasRole("user")
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler());
        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth->oauth.jwt());

        return http.build();
    }
     
}
```

AccessDeniedHandler.java

```java
@Component
public class AccessDeniedHandler implements ServerAccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, AccessDeniedException denied) {
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap.put("status", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        responseMap.put("message", "Unauthorized");
        responseMap.put("data", null);

        byte[] responseBytes=null;
        try {
            responseBytes = serializeToJson(responseMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse()
                .bufferFactory().wrap(responseBytes)));
    }
    
    private byte[] serializeToJson(Object obj) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(obj);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081
    
logging:
  level:
    '[org.springframework.security]': DEBUG
    '[org.keycloak]': DEBUG

 
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8181/realms/Metaverse
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          
jwt:
  auth:
    converter:
      resource-id: metaverse_client
      principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apigateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have generated token using user credentials but not able access user services getting access denied error, how to resolve and what I'm missing

I have generated token through postman by using client id and token URL using "user" credentials but not able access user services getting access denied error, how to resolve and what I'm missing

1. in securityconfig class
   .pathMatchers("/samp/b").hasRole("user")

not able to access this using genenrated above token and same thing happens for admin using token generated by admin credentials

```
The output console debug
```

```
 main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8081
2023-09-14 14:01:09.168  INFO 20040 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8081
2023-09-14 14:01:09.649  INFO 20040 --- [           main] c.i.i.apigateway.ApiServiceApplication   : Started ApiServiceApplication in 5.371 seconds (JVM running for 6.355)
2023-09-14 14:01:38.806  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
2023-09-14 14:01:38.807  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2023-09-14 14:01:38.816  INFO 20040 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
2023-09-14 14:02:21.935 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
2023-09-14 14:02:21.936 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /samp/b' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2023-09-14 14:02:21.936 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2023-09-14 14:02:21.938 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/samp/a', method=null}
2023-09-14 14:02:21.938 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Request 'GET /samp/b' doesn't match 'null /samp/a'
2023-09-14 14:02:21.938 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : No matches found
2023-09-14 14:02:21.938 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/samp/b', method=null}
2023-09-14 14:02:21.940 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] athPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher : Checking match of request : '/samp/b'; against '/samp/b'
2023-09-14 14:02:21.940 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
2023-09-14 14:02:21.940 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/samp/b' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager@167e4c63
2023-09-14 14:02:21.942 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied
```

Comment: please post your full debug logs including stacktraces so that we can see the reason for why your server produces what you call an "access denied error" (which is not a good way to describe an error)

Comment: Checking match of request : '/samp/b'; against '/samp/b'
2023-09-14 14:02:21.940 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.u.m.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher : matched
2023-09-14 14:02:21.940 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on '/samp/b' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager@167e4c63
2023-09-14 14:02:21.942 DEBUG 20040 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.s.w.s.a.AuthorizationWebFilter       : Authorization failed: Access Denied

Comment: please do not post logs/code in comments, use the edit button on your question and add it properly formatted, also which part of "full logs" was unclear, is all your logs, one line during my +10 years with spring i have never seen a service just write a single log line.

Answer (score 1):

## [RTFM](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction)

You did not configure the `jwtAuthenticationConverter` with a `Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>` => the roles in the access token (`realm_access.roles` and `resource_access.{client-id}.roles`) are not turned into Spring authorities.

##### Notes

If writing a new app, you'd better use Spring Boot `3.1.3` (not `2.7.14`)

`jwt.auth.converter` is not part of spring boot standard properties and you didn't provide with the `@ConfigurationProperties` parsing it. If you copied from a tutorial, you forgot that part (and probably the authentication & authorities converters using it).

You'll probably find [my OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) and tutorials useful...

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what it requires for an answer to be acceptable or even just useful.

Comment: you became my goto soln provider.